# Publishing from IDE removes wildcard mapping in IIS7 in classic mode

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis-7, publish

I have an ASP.Net app that I deploy to a IIS 7.0 server in classic mode.

I use the publish feature from the Visual Studio IDE. Every time
I perform a publish, the wild card mapping is removed. Anyone know
how to prevent this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard mapping is stored in the application's web.config. You could create the mapping and then copy the section from the system.webServer->handlers section into your dev web.config.

Or you could use a Web.Deploy project to setup the web.config exactly as it needs to be for deployments.